# 1 Domain Controller(s) with replication in progress

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, replication

I have 3 DCs (DC01, DC02 and DC03).

If I create a group policy on any DC I find it replicated to the others.
But I see an error in Group policy management, in domain status if I click “Detect Now” it gives the following:

•   1 Domain Controller(s) with replication in progress

DC03       ACLs

•   1 Domain Controller(s) with replication in sync

DC02

As if the replication failed on DC03 and succeeded on DC02

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: `Any idea about this issue?` start with the command line utilities. `repadmin /showreps` on all DC's.

Comment: I did the following on all Dcs:
Repadmin /replsummary
Repadmin /Queue
Repadmin /Showrepl
Repadmin /syncall
Repadmin /KCC
All succeeded no single error!